# :with clause preventing action from getting executed in link_to_remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I'm experiencing problems with the :with clause in the following code.

```
-counter.times do |c|
  -elem = @tags[c]
  #{elem.name}#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}, :with => "'tag_remove=' + #{elem}"}
```

If I take out the `:with` clause, then `remove_tag_from_cart` gets executed when I click on the image link. But, I can't do anything with `elem` because it's not being passed to remove_tag_from_cart in any way.

If I leave the `:with` clause in there, then `remove_tag_from_cart` does not get executed at all!

From my understanding, :with is supposed to enable me to do this in `remove_tag_from_cart`:

```
def remove_tag_from_cart
  puts params[:tag_remove].name
end
```

Again, if I include the :with clause, this method does not run.

What I'd like is to just pass `elem` or `elem.id` to `remove_tag_from_cart` so that I can use it (to find things, etc.). Is this (i.e., passing it using :with) the best/right way to do that? If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: please post what is your generated html?and what you want?

Comment: Well, this code exists in a partial that's rendered from another Ajax call, so I don't know how to view the html that's generated.

Comment: The problem is as I stated: #{elem.name}#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}, :with => "'tag_remove=' + #{elem}"} includes the :with clause and does NOT execute the remove_tag_from_cart method.

When I remove the :with clause -- that is, when it's just #{elem.name}#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}} -- remove_tag_from_cart is executed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to trace ajax calls, view generated html etc.

`:with` option is (from [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote)):

> A JavaScript expression specifying the
>   parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any
>   expressions should return a valid URL
>   query string.
>
> Example:
>
> `:with => "'name=' + $('name').value"`

You are doing `:with => "'tag_remove=' + #{elem}"`

elem seems to be ActiveRecord object, so it seems that what you really want to do, is to pass it's id with the params. But you can do it with the normal url params, without using javascript's `:with`:

```
link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart', :tag_remove_id => elem.id}
```

and in the conroller use

```
Tag.find(params[:tag_remove_id])
```